# Spell check not working in webkit

Tags: webkit, node-webkit

Spell check is not supporting in webkit.

If we add attribute "spellcheck=true" for the elements which required spell check, its not supported by webkit. Any one know how to deal with this?

Comment: Looks like it isn't included internally. There are at least two open issues about it: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/332 and https://github.com/rhiokim/haroopad/issues/147

Answer (score 1):

node-webkit doesn't support's spell check , But you can find it in electron(previously called atom shell).It's also like a node-webkit Engine .It can render html,javascript and nodejs. If i made any mistake please correct me.